# NullPointerException when changing JavaFX Tab Order

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, tabs, java-platform-module-system, module-info

I downloaded and tried the javafx sample "Draggable and detachable tabs in JavaFX 2" by Michael Berry from https://berry120.blogspot.com/2014/01/draggable-and-detachable-tabs-in-javafx.html

It works just fine in Java 8, but trying it with Java 11 and jigsaw modules is when it breaks. The issue is, that sometimes when I change the order of the tabs, I get a NullPointerException, without the fxtabs-classes even in the stacktrace.

Here's my module-info:

```
module fxtabs {
  exports fxtabs;

  requires javafx.base;
  requires javafx.graphics;
  requires transitive javafx.controls;
}
```

And this is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.input.PickResultChooser.processOffer(PickResultChooser.java:185)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.input.PickResultChooser.offer(PickResultChooser.java:143)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.intersects(Node.java:5219)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node$1.intersects(Node.java:543)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.intersects(NodeHelper.java:258)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3161)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.pickNode(Scene.java:3993)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.pick(Scene.java:2029)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.access$6800(Scene.java:172)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3893)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

btw. surrounding the code with a try/catch also does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to this the next day, the issue magically disappeared. I restarted the computer and now I can no longer reproduce the exception. Might have been some bug in eclipse or the jdk - I don't know - but until it comes back, I consider this problem solved.